# javascript: why the return value is possible to be false

Tags: javascript, function, methods, method-modifier

```
function test() {
    alert(1);
    return "hello";
}

Function.prototype.before = function (func) {
    var __bself = this;
    return function () {
        if (func.apply(this, arguments) == false)
            return false;

        return __bself.apply(__bself, arguments);
    }
};

test.before(function (){
    alert(2);
})();
```

What is the meaning of `if (func.apply(this, arguments) == false)`?
I don't think the function will return false.

Comment: This *particular* function won't return false, but others may...

Comment: Regarding the former `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Functions can return any value. That includes `false`.

If your functions don't return `false` then the code inside that conditional will never run. So you can remove it, if it annoys you for some reason.

Here is an example with a function which returns `false`:

```js
function test() { // This function is never called
  console.log(1);
  return "hello";
}
Function.prototype.before = function (func) {
  var __bself = this;
  return function () {
    if (func.apply(this, arguments) == false){
      return false;
    }
    return __bself.apply(__bself, arguments);
  }
};
test.before(function (){
  console.log(2);
  return false;
})();
```